# String manipulation in Python (All upper and lower case derivatives of a word)

Tags: python, string

I have to read in a word, and create an array which stores every variation of upper and lower case characters for this word in an array. For example with the word "abc". I need to find a way to retrieve every upper and lower case version of "abc" (abc, Abc, ABc, ABC, AbC, abC, and aBC). The string may also include numbers which should be left alone.

I know I would have to use recursion here in order to get every variation, but I'm just not quite sure how, or if there are any python libraries that provide this kind of operation.

Any help or tips is greatly appreciated!

Comment: We can help you with tips to solve specific problems you have. Try implementing a solution first.

Comment: Note that your list of results is missing `aBc` - intentional or mistake?

Comment: Tried anything as yet?

Comment: How is this "random"?

Comment: What should be the output when the input is `abc1`?

Comment: O(2**n) memory usage...what could go wrong?

Comment: You don't _need_ recursion, but you could use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from itertools import product
def randString(istr):
    l = [(c, c.upper()) if not c.isdigit() else (c,) for c in istr.lower()]
    return ["".join(item) for item in product(*l)]

print randString("aBC1")
print randString("A1b2c3")
```

**Output**

```
['abc1', 'abC1', 'aBc1', 'aBC1', 'Abc1', 'AbC1', 'ABc1', 'ABC1']
['a1b2c3', 'a1b2C3', 'a1B2c3', 'a1B2C3', 'A1b2c3', 'A1b2C3', 'A1B2c3', 'A1B2C3']
```

Comment: @icktoofay Nope. As per the question, the input might have numbers as well. We need to filter them out.

Comment: Numbers should be "left alone", not "left out".

Comment: @Tim My bad, what exactly that means? They also should be included?

Comment: Yes. As far as I can tell `'ab1'` should give `'ab1', 'Ab1', 'aB1', 'AB1'`, which complicates the problem.

Comment: @thefourtheye He means that for "A1b2c3", you should output "a1b2c3", "a1B2C3" and so on.

Comment: @Tim Can you check my solution now and tell me if it is fine?

Comment: @icktoofay Please check my solution now, I fixed it for the numbers as well.

Comment: @BlackMamba Please check my answer now. It should do fine for the numbers as well.

Comment: @thefourtheye What is about the input "A1b2c3"?

Comment: @BlackMamba It generates `['a1b2c3', 'a1b2C3', 'a1B2c3', 'a1B2C3', 'A1b2c3', 'A1b2C3', 'A1B2c3', 'A1B2C3']`

Answer (score 5):

You can solve this using a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). Given the string `'abc'`, you'll want to split it into a list of possibilities in each position, e.g.:

```
['Aa', 'Bb', 'Cc']
```

I'll leave that to you, as it should be pretty easy. Once you've got that, you can use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to make all the combinations. You'll get an iterable of lists like

```
['A', 'b', 'C']
```

You can then use `''.join` to join those lists together, getting your desired strings.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `product` like this. The trick is to use sets to manage any characters that don't have distinct upper and lower versions (eg digits).

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [''.join(x) for x in product(*[{c.upper(), c.lower()} for c in "abc"])]
['ABC', 'ABc', 'AbC', 'Abc', 'aBC', 'aBc', 'abC', 'abc']
>>> [''.join(x) for x in product(*[{(c.upper(), c.lower()} for c in "abc1"])]
['ABC1', 'ABc1', 'AbC1', 'Abc1', 'aBC1', 'aBc1', 'abC1', 'abc1']
```

so

```
from itertools import product
def randString(s):
    return [[''.join(x) for x in product(*[{c.upper(), c.lower()} for c in s])]
```

You can make the output more consistent by shifting the `.lower()`

```
from itertools import product
def randString(s):
    return [[''.join(x) for x in product(*[{c.upper(), c} for c in s.lower()])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the good ol' recursion:

```
def get_all_variations(word):
    if len(word) == 1:
        #a single character has two variations. e.g. a -> [a, A]
        return [word, word.upper()]
    else:
        #otherwise, call recursively using the left and the right half, and merge results.
        word_mid_point = len(word) // 2
        left_vars = get_all_variations(word[:word_mid_point])
        right_vars = get_all_variations(word[word_mid_point:])
        variations = []
        for left_var in left_vars:
            for right_var in right_vars:
                variations.append(left_var + right_var)
        return variations
```

and

```
>>> get_all_variations("abc")
['abc', 'abC', 'aBc', 'aBC', 'Abc', 'AbC', 'ABc', 'ABC']
```

Answer (score -3):

If this isn't homework, you can probably:

```
print(list(itertools.combinations('abcABC', 3)))
```

Comment: Not quite. That will rearrange the letters.

Comment: input is any word, not a set of characters

Comment: The second result is `('a', 'b', 'A')` which should not be there.

Comment: If you delete this answer now, you will get `Peer Pressure` badge :)