# specific word count differs for lower cased vs lower+title version

Tags: python, nltk

I'm obviously missing something easy and my guess is that some other casing of 'whale' exists in text1.  More important than the answer is how does one efficiently debug this, short of a case insensitive search for 'whale' in text1 and text1L?

Thanks, it's early days for me in NLTK.

```
import nltk
from nltk.book import *
text1L=[w.lower() for w in text1]
print(text1L.count('whale'))
>>>1226
print(text1.count('Whale')+text1.count('whale'))
>>>1188
```

Comment: Have you checked to make sure there are no instances of 'WHale' or 'wHale' or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with the following code to see that you have also 'WHALE' in `text1`

```
>>> res = [j for j in (w for w in text1
               if all(i in w.lower() for i in 'whale')
               and len(w) == 5) if j not in ('Whale', 'whale')]
>>> len(res)  # 38 = 1226 - 1188
38
>>> 
>>> res
['WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE', 'WHALE']
```

So, now you have:

```
>>> [w.lower() for w in text1].count('whale')
1226
>>>
>>> text1.count('Whale') + text1.count('whale') + text1.count('WHALE')
1226
```

Comment: btw `i in list(w.lower())` => `i in w.lower()`. Your code-golf is improving :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few WHALEs.

```
whale 906
Whale 282
WHALE 38
```

So:

```
print(text1.count('Whale') + text1.count('whale') + text1.count('WHALE'))
>> 1226
```

To figure this out, all the variations of the word "whale" were generated, and the variations with a non-zero count were printed out.

Generating variations:

```
def get_all_variations(word):
    if len(word) == 1:
        #a single character has two variations. e.g. a -> [a, A]
        return [word, word.upper()]
    else:
        #otherwise, call recursively using the left and the right half, and merge results.
        word_mid_point = len(word) // 2
        left_vars = get_all_variations(word[:word_mid_point])
        right_vars = get_all_variations(word[word_mid_point:])
        variations = []
        for left_var in left_vars:
            for right_var in right_vars:
                variations.append(left_var + right_var)
        return variations
```

and then:

```
whale_variations = get_all_variations("whale")
for whale_varitaion in whale_variations:
    count = text1.count(whale_varitaion)
    if count > 0:
        print(whale_varitaion, count)
```

---

As a side note, all the variations are kind of neat to look at:

> 'whale,whalE,whaLe,whaLE,whAle,whAlE,whALe,whALE,wHale,wHalE,wHaLe,wHaLE,wHAle,wHAlE,wHALe,wHALE,Whale,WhalE,WhaLe,WhaLE,WhAle,WhAlE,WhALe,WhALE,WHale,WHalE,WHaLe,WHaLE,WHAle,WHAlE,WHALe,WHALE'

Comment: ok, but what's the point of the variations part? how does _that_ answer the question? I suggest that you focus on answering OP interrogations.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The OP is unable to match the counts because they missed "WHALE". Of course, that wasn't known beforehand (hence the question). Thus, I had to do an exhaustive search and see which variation(s) make up for the lost 38. I've nonetheless edited the answer to be more explicit, thank for the input.

Comment: I still don't understand the variation parts. but the numbers add up.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre if we have multiple of these queries, and a word index, this solution will be way faster. On the other hand, solution by ettanany, albeit correct, will need one pass over the index or the document for each query.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through a `nltk.Text` object returns a list of strings, and each string is a word, using `map()` might be a good idea if you're applying the same operation to all strings in the list.

```
>>> from nltk.book import * 
>>> text1_lowered = list(map(str.lower, text1))
>>> text1_lowered.count('whale')
1226
>>> text1_lowered.count('Whale')
0
>>> text1.count('Whale') + text1.count('whale')
1188
```

To answer the mystery of where the other "whales" are coming from such that we get 1226:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter([word for word in text1 if word.lower() == 'whale'])
Counter({'whale': 906, 'Whale': 282, 'WHALE': 38})
```

---

A note on @axiom idea to generate all possible upper/lower case combinations of "whale", see [String manipulation in Python (All upper and lower case derivatives of a word)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20063721/string-manipulation-in-python-all-upper-and-lower-case-derivatives-of-a-word)

```
>>> from itertools import product

>>> cRaZySpe3K = lambda s: [''.join(x) for x in product(*[{c.upper(), c} for c in s.lower()])]

>>> cRaZySpe3K('whale')
['WHALe', 'WHALE', 'WHAle', 'WHAlE', 'WHaLe', 'WHaLE', 'WHale', 'WHalE', 'WhALe', 'WhALE', 'WhAle', 'WhAlE', 'WhaLe', 'WhaLE', 'Whale', 'WhalE', 'wHALe', 'wHALE', 'wHAle', 'wHAlE', 'wHaLe', 'wHaLE', 'wHale', 'wHalE', 'whALe', 'whALE', 'whAle', 'whAlE', 'whaLe', 'whaLE', 'whale', 'whalE']

>>> {whale:text1.count(whale) for whale in cRaZySpe3K('whale')}
{'WHALe': 0, 'WHALE': 38, 'WHAle': 0, 'WHAlE': 0, 'WHaLe': 0, 'WHaLE': 0, 'WHale': 0, 'WHalE': 0, 'WhALe': 0, 'WhALE': 0, 'WhAle': 0, 'WhAlE': 0, 'WhaLe': 0, 'WhaLE': 0, 'Whale': 282, 'WhalE': 0, 'wHALe': 0, 'wHALE': 0, 'wHAle': 0, 'wHAlE': 0, 'wHaLe': 0, 'wHaLE': 0, 'wHale': 0, 'wHalE': 0, 'whALe': 0, 'whALE': 0, 'whAle': 0, 'whAlE': 0, 'whaLe': 0, 'whaLE': 0, 'whale': 906, 'whalE': 0}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since the question is "how do I debug this kind of "what am I missing" situation", I would start with figuring out what you are missing. The simplest way is usually to form a set:

```
>>> print(set(w for w in text1 if w.lower() == "whale"))
{'whale', 'WHALE', 'Whale'}
```

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain? It's the simplest solution yet -- and arguably the most general.